# Canvas и прозрачность

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, typescript

С помощью канваса делаю скриншот видео, на котором может быть одновременно несколько видео\картинок. Так вот если поставить у картинки, назовем ее к примеру "А", прозрачность в 0.5. При попытке сделать скриншот, у "А" прозрачность пропадает вообще... Возможно ли через канву сохранять прозрачность у разных объектов ?

Comment: интересно, как вы при помощи канваса делаете скриншот видео?

Comment: Да, покажите метод, которым вы извлекаете кадр, куда сохраняете в каком виде, как устанавливаете альфа значение...

Comment: Предположу, что теряется прозрачность в jpg, ее там нет) Нужно в png

Comment: увы... "await canvas.toDataURL('image/png');"

Comment: добавьте воспроизводимый пример в вопрос, там для этого есть специальная кнопка

Comment: Качество данных (от 0 до 1) случайно не указываете? Как потом используете полученные данные? Откуда узнаете, что прозрачность сбежала и как она устанавливается перед извлечением данных?